# How would I define duplicate keys in a json array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am making a program that parses json files for dnd information. I have completed the program, however, I cannot figure out how to define the duplicate keys for the various attacks without manually giving thousands of keys unique ids.

Part of my JSON file:

```
{
  "special_abilities": [
    {
      "name": "Legendary Resistance (3/Day)",
      "desc": "If the tarrasque fails a saving throw, it can choose to succeed instead.",
      "attack_bonus": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Magic Resistance",
      "desc": "The tarrasque has advantage on saving throws against spells and other magical effects.",
      "attack_bonus": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Reflective Carapace",
      "desc": "Any time the tarrasque is targeted by a magic missile spell, a line spell, or a spell that requires a ranged attack roll, roll a d6. On a 1 to 5, the tarrasque is unaffected. On a 6, the tarrasque is unaffected, and the effect is reflected back at the caster as though it originated from the tarrasque, turning the caster into the target.",
      "attack_bonus": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Siege Monster",
      "desc": "The tarrasque deals double damage to objects and structures.",
      "attack_bonus": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

So, how would I define each of the `name` keys? 
If I can define what I posted up there as `searchFile.special_abilities`, how would I define `searchFile.special_abilities.name`?

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: You need to change `special_abilities` into an object that's indexed by `name`

Comment: A lot of internet searching, `searchFile.special_abilities.name` and `searchFile.special_abilities.name[1]`

Comment: With "define" you mean "access" ?

Comment: You just need to do `searchFile.special_abilities[i].name`, where `i` is an integer which you change to access each individual ability.

Comment: Jonas Wilms, yes that is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is valid. You would access the parsed JSON data like so:

```
const searchFile = JSON.parse(jsonVarName)

const index = 2 // or whatever index you want

const name = searchFile.special_abilities[index].name
```

You can also use the various [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) to do all sorts of interesting things with the data, like searching by name:

```
const siegeMonster = searchFile.special_abilities.find(ability => ability.name === 'Siege Monster')
```

Comment: Give me an upvote so I don’t look like a fool please. Hahaha

Comment: Haha, it’s cool man, welcome to SO. I wasn’t holding my breath.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a object of arrays instead, indexed by name, that way the name is never duplicated, and there's no need for separate unique identifiers. For example:

```
"special_abilities": {
  "Some Name": [
    {
      "desc": "Description 1",
      "attack_bonus": 0
    },
    {
      "desc": "Description 2",
      "attack_bonus": 5
    }
  ],
  "Some Other Name": [
    {
      "desc": "Some Other Description",
      "attack_bonus": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, you could access `special_abilities['Some name']` to get to the array, and iterate over the array to find what you're looking for. (Use `Object.entries` to get both the key and the value at once, eg `Object.entries(special_abilities).forEach(([name, arr]) => { ...`  )

Comment: The problem with this, it that I would have to manually implement it for thousands of other monsters in the json file as well.